# Rainbow Six : Siege won't update and can't play

Tags: steam, ubisoft-connect, rainbow-six-siege

Yesterday Rainbow Six worked fine, but today something strange happened. I wanted to surf the shop, and the game won't update, and I get this error saying `Update failed`, with two options `retry` and `cancel`, and everytime when I retry nothing happens. Because of this error, I can't play either.

I tried to do some things, maybe they would work but everything was for nothing, they're listed below.

- Changing DNS to 8.8.8.8 - 4.2.2.4
- Deleting R6 folder on my documents
- Reinstalling the game
- Reinstalling Steam and Uplay
- Resetting pc / internet
- Running the game with administrator rights
- Disabling Firewall

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to play this game you'll need to get into some trouble:
When I had the same problem, most of the things you tried didn't work for me either. I read that some Windows patches prevent you from playing some games.
Try to reinstall your Windows, then install Uplay/Steam, and finally use your product key to install the game. If that also doesn't work contact Ubisoft.

Comment: damn man this post is so old ahahah, everything's alright now, I don't remember how i fixed it though, but guess I'll let it open if someone can get a concrete answer

Comment: No problem I answered it just for answering

Comment: Do you have any sources you can share about those Windows patches you mention?